# iOS [ARC] app not releasing memory

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory

My application, during a process I've written, is rising in memory and seems to not be releasing it.

The first thing I'd like to mention is that the basic outline of what I've written is this:
 - Request a url (fetching data using NSData -initWithContentsOfURL)
 - Parse NSData into NSArray of NSDictionarys using NSJSONSerialization +JSONObjectWithStream
 - Loop through decoded NSArray inserting/updating/deleting records in a sqlite database using the FMDB framework with the data decoded

The application does the above, however it does it in a loop for an undetermined period of time, in which the application displays a "Loading" HUD. I thought it may be worth mentioning this, although I find it insignificant how many times it does this process, as that shouldn't affect the memory usage if it were releasing properly. If I am wrong here, please advise me.

My code works fine, well, it does what it's intended to do. However, when I profile the application code, the memory seems to just keep rising. It does drop in segments throughout, but overall it keeps rising (IE doesn't release in full what it previously used).

I have, as previously stated, profiled the application with Allocations, Leaks, VM Tracker, and used Trace Highlights.

**Trace Highlights**: Shows that the memory usage is gradually going up, but dropping some memory (not all) meaning if the process is running for long enough the memory will reach high usage and terminate.

**Allocations**: Seems OK. The allocations has spikes but always comes back down to where it started. I took heapshots and they always drop down leaving maximum 500-700kb per segment (left for about 10 minutes)

**VM Tracker**: Proves to show that memory consistently rises, and is not releasing full memory (as discovered in trace highlights). Resident seems to get really high

**Leaks**: No leaks found in application

Here's some screenshots of Allocations/VM Tracker running:
[image]
[image]

It's worth noting that I have in fact tried:
- Adding autoreleasepools
- "force releasing" by assigning each properties; such as NSURLs, NSRequests, etc; to nil

**My questions:**
- Should I be doing something special to release the memory?
- How could I further debug this issue?
- How best can I find out what's wrong from the data Instruments gives me?

---- **EDIT:** ----
Here's the code that sends the url request to fetch the data.:

```
- (void) requestAndParse : (NSString *)url 
{
    NSURL *theURL;
    ASIHTTPRequest *request;
    NSData *collectedData;
    NSError *error;
    @try {
                    // File cache the NSData
                    theURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: url];
                    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL: theURL];
                    [request setDownloadDestinationPath: [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingString:@"/cachefile.txt"]];
                    [request startSynchronous];
                    [request waitUntilFinished];

                    collectedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingString:@"/cachefile.txt"]];


                    if ([collectedData length] > 0) {
                        records = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:collectedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                    }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

                    // Failed
                    NSLog(@"Parse error: %@", error);

    }
    @finally {

                    // DB updates with the records here
                    ...

                    // remove file
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingString:@"/cachefile.txt"] error:nil];
                    // release properties used
                    collectedData = nil;
                    request = nil;
                    theURL = nil;
    }

}
```

This above method is called from within a while loop in the Application Delegate. The while loop is an undetermined length, as previously mentioned.

**--- EDIT 2: ---**

The following is what happens within the @finally statement (updating the SQLite database using FMDB). There are a lot of these methods in my class, one for each table. They all follow the same pattern though, as they are all duplicated from the first one:

```
-(BOOL) insertBatchOfRecords:(NSArray *)records {

__block BOOL queueReturned = YES;

@autoreleasepool {

    FMDatabaseQueue *dbQueue = [self instantiateDatabaseQueue];
    [dbQueue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *tdb, BOOL *rollback) {
        if (![tdb open]) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't open DB inside Transaction");
            queueReturned = NO;
            *rollback = YES;
            return;
        }

        for (NSDictionary *record in records) {
            [tdb executeUpdate:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (attr1, attr2) VALUES (?,?)", [record valueForKey:@"attr1"], [record valueForKey:@"attr2"]];

            if ([tdb hadError]) {
                queueReturned = NO;
                *rollback = YES;
                NSLog(@"Failed to insert records because %@", [tdb lastErrorMessage]);
                return;
            }
        }
    }];

    [dbQueue close];
    dbQueue = nil;

}

return queueReturned;
}
```

And follows is the -instantiateDatabaseQueue method:

```
-(FMDatabaseQueue *) instantiateDatabaseQueue {
@autoreleasepool {
    return [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath: [self.getDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localdb.db"]];
}
}
```

The autoreleasepools may make it messy, but the code originally did not have these. I implemented them in various locations to see if there was any improvement (there was not).

**--- EDIT 3 ---**

I have been profiling the application the past few days, and still have no luck in finding an answer. I have separated the part of the app in question to a separate project of it's own, to make sure that it is indeed this causing the memory usage. This proved to be correct, as the app is still acting the same.

I have taken further profiling pictures, and am still having a hard time identifying what is actually wrong. See below that the allocations looks OK (the VM also doesn't look too bad to me?), and there's still no leaks (no picture of this, because there's none!!)

However, when I profiled on Trace Highlights, the memory usage just keeps going up, until reaching too much usage (around 70+MB on a 3GS) and then crashes due to using so much memory.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I reduced the problem by using ASIHTTPRequest for grabbing the NSData (stores to file instead). Please see revised code above. However, problem still persists, just takes longer to happen!

As per originally, **question**:
- Is there something wrong with the second part of this app process?

Comment: +1 nice first question. Might need to include some code, though.

Comment: Have you used stackshots to see what the new allocations actually are? Are you giving the runloop an opportunity to run? (Consider breaking your long loop into smaller operations and processing them with an NSOperationQueue).

Comment: I've included the actual code that sends the URL request and breaks it down into an array.

Comment: I will checkout NSOperationQueue and will use stackshots

Comment: Problem still persists, but the allocations results looks perfectly fine, only on the Trace Highlights it displays a climb of "Real Memory Usage" still, and will crash when this hits too high.

Please see revised post

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to solve this problem using the methods of database usage used here. I converted the database usage to CoreData and used ASIHTTPRequest instead of regular NSRequest to fetch the data from URL (storing the data in a file cache). These conversions together have took the app back to normal memory usage, so I can only guess that the problem probably ocurred during either FMDB Framework (or my usage of it), or the constant NSRequests in storing data in memory (probability that it was both).

Answer (score 1):

Using try / catch in iOS with ARC can cause memory leaks, and is best avoided.

an alternative approach is to use an async NSURLConnection, or an NSOperation with a synch NSURLConnection.

Comment: Very true. It's sad but true.

Comment: In this instance the try/catch used is not causing the leak, which i'm certain of as the try catch was implemented after I noticed this problem. Async NSURLConnection was also used but it was changed to synchronous as the main thread was being blocked until the async finished anyway. NExt step is to check out the NSOperation usage which I will be doing today and will post back with the results.

Comment: In that case are you sure that the requestAndParse method is causing the leaks?

Comment: I have now implemented the NSOperationQueue and it seems to still be pushing memory up and up. I will post back how I'm using FMDB to the OP.